# opening a QWidget from another Qwidget with different file

Tags: python, pyqt5

i have this file let's say widgetA.py

```
import sys, requests, json
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QWidget, QDesktopWidget

)

class main(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setFixedSize(254, 380)
        self.center()
        self.show()

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    x = main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

how can i open that widget from another widget let say widgetB.py using a QPushButton

widgetB.py has exactly the same structure with addition of a button

```
import widgetA    
...
class main(QWidget):
....
   def initUI(self):
      openwidget = QPushbutton('open', self)
      openwidget.clicked.connect(widgetA.show)
      self.setFixedSize(254, 380)
      self.center()
      self.show()
....
....
```

Comment: show widgetB.py

Comment: try with: `openwidget.buttonClicked.connect(self.widgetA.show)`

Comment: widgetB.py has exactly the same structure with addition of a button `openwidget = QPushbutton('open', self)` inside `initUI()`

Comment: if both widgets are the same except for the pushbutton...(confused)... why al this trouble... besides the confusion you should also add positioning information... if you use wdgetB twice... two-buttons.. one spot... hmmm.. you can simply use button.hide() and or button.show().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm i'm such an idiot it's seems you cant declare QWidget twice so i change one of them as QDialog, i'm still learning so please bear with me X__X

widgeta.py :

```
class widgetA(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(widgetA, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()
```

then this is in widgetb.py :

```
from widgeta import widgetA

class widgetB(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(widgetB, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()
        self.show()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setFixedSize(254, 380)
        self.center()
        button = QPushButton('open', self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.openwindow)
        self.openwindow = widgetA()

    def openwindow(self):
        self.openwindow.exec()
```